# Check whether a list is sublist of another list in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Below is the code snippet of a stored procedure in **Oracle 12C**. My goal here is to find whether a list (prepared using select statement) is a sublist of another list(pre defined list of 5 items).

```
TYPE TYPE_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(200);
CHILD_ITEMS TYPE_LIST;
PARENT_ITEMS TYPE_LIST := TYPE_LIST('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5');

-- collect child items
SELECT A.NAME BULK COLLECT INTO CHILD_ITEMS FROM TABLE_A A, TABLE_B B WHERE A.ID = B.ITEM_ID ;
```

If `CHILD_ITEMS`  is sublist of `PARENT_ITEMS` (in this case if all items of `CHILD_ITEMS` are part of `PARENT_ITEMS ('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5')`), I have to perform some steps.

if say `CHILD_ITEMS` contains `'item1','item2'` condition should return true.
if say `CHILD_ITEMS` contains `'item1','item2','item100'` condition should return false since `'item100'` isn't part of `PARENT_ITEMS` .

So how to write `IF condition` in this scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`SUBMULTISET` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html#GUID-6EC9172B-DF92-469B-B8BD-E7FFFCEFB37B):

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE TYPE_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(200);
  CHILD_ITEMS TYPE_LIST := TYPE_LIST('item1', 'item3');
  PARENT_ITEMS TYPE_LIST := TYPE_LIST('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5');
BEGIN
  IF child_items SUBMULTISET OF parent_items THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Is subset.' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Is not subset.' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> Is subset.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=49b37088503b5cef2266e5503482bc90)*